# SQL - SELECT With Multiple WHERE Conditions On New Column Rather Than New Row

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join

I have an SQLite database of phrases and their native translations in the form

```
code | language_id | script_source | script_target | transliteration
     |             |               |               |
yes  |      1      |     Yes.      |     Yes.      | NULL
no   |      1      |     No.       |     No.       | NULL
yes  |      3      |     Oui.      |     Oui.      | NULL
no   |      3      |     Non.      |     Non.      | NULL
```

where the language_id specifies the language. I am trying to write a query that `SELECT`'s the code, the script_source from one language and the script_target from another language as well as the transliteration, **all on one row**. The closest I have managed to get is

```
SELECT code, script_source, transliteration FROM phrases WHERE language_id=001
  UNION
SELECT code, script_target, transliteration FROM phrases WHERE language_id=003;
```

which produces this query result:

```
code | script_source | transliteration
yes  |      Yes.     |      NULL                   
yes  |      Oui.     |      NULL  
no   |      No.      |      NULL                   
no   |      Non.     |      NULL
```

This is ok, but it would  be better for my purposes if the `script_target' had it's own column, like this:

```
code | script_source | script_target | transliteration
yes  |      Yes.     |      Oui.     |      NULL   
no   |      No.      |      Non.     |      NULL
```

I think this will probably require a `JOIN` function of some sort, but as of yet I haven't been able to get the desired result. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** My mistake, I want the transliteration corresponding to the `script_target` value.

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are two different products with slightly different sql syntax and vastly different features. Pls only use the relevant product tags for your question.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) are different, unrelated software packages produced by different companies/persons. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: Btw this transformation is called pivoting and the result is called pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a `join`:

```
SELECT p1.code, p1.script_source,p2.script_source as script_target, 
       p2.transliteration as transliateration
FROM phrases p1 JOIN
     phrases p2
     ON p1.code = p2.code
WHERE p1.language_id = 1 AND p2.language_id = 3;
```

It is not clear which transliteration you want.

Comment: This works well, but (sorry for not clarifying) I only want the transliteration for script_target.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed set of `language_id` values you can do something like:

```
SELECT code, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN language_id = 1 THEN script_source END) AS script_source, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN language_id = 3 THEN script_target END) AS script_target,
       MAX(CASE WHEN language_id = 3 THEN transliteration END) AS transliteration 
FROM phrases 
WHERE language_id IN (1,3)
GROUP BY code
```

The above query picks the `transliteration` value that corresponds to `language_id = 3`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a join :-)

```
SELECT 
  source.code, 
  source.script_source, 
  source.transliteration as source_transliteration,
  target.script_taget, 
  target.transliteration as target_transliteration
FROM phrases source
JOIN phrases target ON target.code = source.code
WHERE source.language_id = 001
  AND target.language_id = 003;
```